# Excel 2010 data import from mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, odbc, pivot-table, time-format

I'm trying to import data from a `MySQL` database into an Excel workbook via an `ODBC Data Source`.

I have a big problem with the `time(3)` fields from `MySQL`. Excel imports the content not as expected. As first try, Excel cut the milliseconds off. Then I edited the query at the specific fields to:

```
DATE_FORMAT(jobstat_0.PreProcessingQueued,'%T,%f')
```

This puts something like:

```
00:00:00,156000
```

That's what I expected, *but* I can not **change the format** in Excel.

Excel interprets the content as **text**, and if I change to the specific time format, Excel does not care...

I need to correct that to get **Pivot Tables** working. As a result there are `Divide By Zero` errors in my Pivot Table.

May be someone had something like that?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!**  Please take a few minutes to check out the [tour] and there are also important tips in [ask] as well as tips about **providing examples** at [mcve].  We like to see that some ***effort*** has been made in researching to finding a solution ***before*** asking for help (on a _specific_ problem), so please includes details about what you've tried so far.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please [edit] to add **examples** of what your data *looks like*, and what it *needs to* look like, to help others understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: ...but a hint for you: when having a problem with a function (`DATE_FORMAT` in this case), thoroughly read the documentation.   In this case one (of many) pages that could help you is [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) : `DATE_FORMAT()` **`returns a *STRING*`** `with a character set and collation given by character_set_connection and collation_connection so that it can return month and weekday names containing non-ASCII characters.` *Date* data types are not the same as *String* data types.

Comment: okay, thanks for your hint. If I execute the SQL Query "by hand" I can not find any non ASCII chars ...